# The name of a game from the 2013 Putnam

Tags: contest-math, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Does the following game from the 2013 Putnam have an official name?  Based on my searches, it seems to have been created just for the exam.

Let $n\geq 1$ be an odd integer.  Alice and Bob play the  following game, taking alternating turns, with Alice playing first. The playing area consists of $n$ spaces, arranged in a line. Initially all spaces are empty. At each turn, a player either

• places a stone in an empty space, or

• removes a stone from a nonempty space $s$, places a stone in the nearest empty space to the left of s (if such a space exists), and places a stone in the nearest empty space to the right of s (if such a space exists).

Furthermore, a move is permitted only if the resulting position has not occurred previously in the game. A player loses if he or she is unable to move. Assuming that both players play optimally throughout the game, what moves may Alice make on her first turn?